# Flickering when using numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes() with opencv's VideoCapture stream

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, opencv3.0, pyglet

I just started graphics programming with pyglet. opencv's VideoCapture stream outputs BGR numpy arrays, and most online tutorials/solutions use array.tostring() or array.tobyte() to let pyglet.image.ImageData construct the texture. It works but the conversion is relatively slow ~30 ms per frame. Then I started trying out ctypes arrays:

```
import pyglet
import numpy as np
import cv2
from threading import Thread

stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
_, frame_raw = stream.read()
SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH, NCOLOR = frame_raw.shape
window = pyglet.window.Window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()

def get_from_stream():
    global frame_raw
    while True:
        _, frame_raw = stream.read()

thread_get_from_stream = Thread(target=get_from_stream)
thread_get_from_stream.daemon = True
thread_get_from_stream.start()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    # image = pyglet.image.ImageData(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'BGR', frame_raw[:, ::-1, :].tobytes(), -SCREEN_WIDTH * 3)  # flip horizontally
    image = pyglet.image.ImageData(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'BGR', np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(frame_raw[:, ::-1, :].ravel()), -SCREEN_WIDTH * 3) # flip as well 
    # image = pyglet.image.ImageData(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'BGR', np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(frame_raw[:, ::-1, :].copy().ravel()), -SCREEN_WIDTH * 3) # copy and flip
    # image = pyglet.image.ImageData(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'BGR', np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(frame_raw.ravel()), -SCREEN_WIDTH * 3) # no flip
    image.blit(0, 0)
    fps_display.draw()

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(lambda x: None, 1/30.)
pyglet.app.run()
```

See the four lines in on_draw(). The first line with `frame_raw[:, ::-1, :].tobytes()` works at ~20FPS. What's strange about the second is that there is a lot of flickering alternating between black screen and images, and during the flickering some images are flipped, some are not! I thought this has anything to do with how views are seen at lower levels, but when I use the third line with a copy(), the situation is the same as if copy never happened! Then when I use the fourth line, there is no strange flipping issues but flickering still persists.

I tried disabling `double_buffer` in a config and passed it to window's constructor, but that didn't help.

What's going on?

Update:

Discussion with Dan Mašek. Putting a lock:

```
import pyglet
import numpy as np
import cv2
from threading import Thread, Lock

stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
_, frame_raw = stream.read()
SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH, NCOLOR = frame_raw.shape
window = pyglet.window.Window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()
lock_stream = Lock()

def get_from_stream():
    global frame_raw
    while True:
        with lock_stream:
            _, frame_raw = stream.read()

thread_get_from_stream = Thread(target=get_from_stream)
thread_get_from_stream.daemon = True
thread_get_from_stream.start()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    with lock_stream:
        # image = pyglet.image.ImageData(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'BGR', frame_raw[:, ::-1, :].tobytes(), -SCREEN_WIDTH * 3)
        image = pyglet.image.ImageData(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'BGR', np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(frame_raw[:, ::-1, :].ravel()), -SCREEN_WIDTH * 3)
        # image = pyglet.image.ImageData(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'BGR', np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(frame_raw.ravel()), -SCREEN_WIDTH * 3)
    image.blit(0, 0)
    fps_display.draw()

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(lambda x: None, 1/30.)
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any synchronization around `frame_raw`, yet it's modified in one thread and used in the other. IIRC `VideoCapture` reuses the frame buffer, so without synchronization even the `copy` you make can potentially happen in the middle of a frame decode.

Comment: OK... Putting a thread lock on both ends results in 6 fps, and `frame_raw.ravel()` has images while `frame_raw[:, ::-1, :].ravel()` has a constant black frame, regardless of copying or not.

Comment: Putting the lock on either end is not changing the behavior of the main post.

Comment: Can you please update the question to show your code changes?